# How to highlight elements in a Chrome Extension similar to how DevTools does it?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm interested in creating a Chrome Extension which lists all the elements on the webpage that have an 'id' attribute in a menu. Then, when the user clicks on the element in the menu, the corresponding element on the webpage is highlighted.

I saw Chrome devtools highlights an element when you right click and inspect on it. I'm curious if there is some highlighting API accessible from DevTools? If not, how does one highlight elements similar to how devtools does it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<del>Chrome API does not provide access to such highlighting; you'll need to implement it yourself with an overlay.</del>

Chrome API *does* provide access to the same functionality as DevTools if you use the `debugger` API. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45990544/934239) for details.

Before Chrome 63 (2017-12-06), writing a DevTools extension (i.e. using `devtools.*` APIs to display UI in DevTools) and using `debugger` at the same time would've been impossible, as only one instance of a debugger protocol client was allowed at once. This [has changed](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/devtools-release-notes#multi-client), so now it's a viable answer, even if the documentation for `chrome.debugger` API wasn't updated yet.

Even though it's now *possible*, be aware that `debugger` API is an API with heavy warnings (adding it after publication may auto-disable installed extensions - needs testing).

Below is the original answer:

---

You can implement the highlighting yourself with an overlay.

You can study how it's usually done by looking, for example, at the [element picker](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/blob/5cc7a3a8524371ce8d7ab669813b80ef09276c7f/src/js/scriptlets/element-picker.js#L228) of uBlock Origin.

In short, that method creates an SVG overlay using, among other things, [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) of the elements selected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the example you gave seems very useful.

Comment: This answer contains incorrect information, the debugger API does provide access to this functionality

Comment: @nickford Thanks for notifying me of the second answer. I'll edit my answer shortly. I doubt I can delete an accepted answer, and besides `debugger` API has drawbacks. I'll try to describe what's possible with it in the answer and leave my old advice as an alternative.

Comment: Yeah, I just did some digging through the Vue.js devtools source and found that even though it's a devtools extension, they still aren't using the debugger API to do the highlighting... Interesting.

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/blob/dev/src/backend/highlighter.js

Comment: @Xan, The devtools one can only do bland color highlighting isn't it? What if you need something better?

Comment: @Pacerier See the other answer that expands on debugger API capabilities. It states that color is variable. Also, worst case, second part of my answer gives you full control.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the exact API that Chrome DevTools are using. You will need to call [highlightQuad](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Overlay/#method-highlightQuad) or [highlightNode](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Overlay/#method-highlightNode) via [debugger API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger). You can even specify the color and you can be certain that the highlight will render correctly and not interfere with the website (injecting an 'overlay' node, as Xan suggested, doesn't guarantee that). On the other hand, it will be much trickier to get right and user won't be able to use both your extension and DevTools at the same time (there can be only one debugger API connection). [This code](https://github.com/kdzwinel/DevToolsVoiceCommands/blob/26d2f8a78bb681a121bddd62e4cb57225e726304/scripts/lib/commands/node-inspection.js#L29) should get you started.

Comment: See https://crbug.com/590878 - multi-client debugger/devtools works in Canary when `chrome://flags/#enable-devtools-experiments` is enabled.

Comment: @Konrad, The devtools one can only do bland color highlighting isn't it? What if you need something better?

Comment: @Pacerier see linked docs, you can do any color and any shape you want.

Comment: Is there similar functionality for Firefox? At a first glance - can't seem to be able to find it.